# Cant Manage to use correctly SharedPreferences on my Main.dart on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

I've been learning Flutter and learned this to improve usage with Pub.dev package Shared Preferences,
To sum up, it is to create a service that I can consume and work in a better way all around my app with SharedPreferences, it works perfectly on my Code for `token` because I have my async function

[image: Example how to use Set for Shared Prefrences]

So, the getMethod works perfectly using `final token = await keyValueStorageService.getValue<String>('token')` (also async function above),
but I can't manage to use this code on my UI code, it gives me this instead (Because of the lack of an await function)

[image: Future dyanamic]

but as I read you can use it and initiate (shown below) on your main.dart, I've been trying to use a method `getSharedPrefs()` on the `main.dart` to implement and use it all around my app for example calling my `getValue('user')` wherever I need to but haven't made it work

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Enviroment.initEnvirontment();
  //! Key Value instance for main async 
  await KeyValueStorageServiceImpl().getSharedPrefs();
  await initializeDateFormatting('es_ES', null);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp())));
}
```

My actual code is this

key_value_storage.dart

```
import 'key_value_storage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class KeyValueStorageServiceImpl extends KeyValueStorageService {

  Future<SharedPreferences> getSharedPrefs() async {
    return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  @override
  Future<T?> getValue<T>(String key) async {
    final prefs = await getSharedPrefs();
    switch (T) {
      case String:
        return prefs.getString(key) as T?;
      case int:
        return prefs.getInt(key) as T?;
      case double:
        return prefs.getDouble(key) as T?;
      case bool:
        return prefs.getBool(key) as T?;
      case List:
        return prefs.getStringList(key) as T?;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'No implementation Get for ${T.runtimeType}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> removeKey(String key) async {
    final prefs = await getSharedPrefs();
    return await prefs.remove(key);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setKeyValue<T>(String key, T value) async {
    final prefs = await getSharedPrefs();

    switch (T) {
      case String:
        await prefs.setString(key, value as String);
        break;
      case int:
        await prefs.setInt(key, value as int);
        break;
      case double:
        await prefs.setDouble(key, value as double);
        break;
      case bool:
        await prefs.setBool(key, value as bool);
        break;
      case List:
        await prefs.setStringList(key, value as List<String>);
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'No implementation Set for  ${T.runtimeType}');
    }
  }
}
```

key_value_class.dart

```
abstract class KeyValueStorageService {
  Future<void> setKeyValue<T>(String key, T value);
  Future<T?> getValue<T>(String key);
  Future<bool> removeKey(String key);
}
```

Comment: Can you add relevant UI code which leads to this problem? And you could initiate that call to the `getValue` function inside `initState` function of a`StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Hello, I didn't add any UI code because what I need is to use it as I please, I mean as Text on a Container, as a Title for a Drawer, etc. Not in a specific widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What & why I made the changes:

1. Store an instance of `SharedPreferences` in the `KeyValueStorageServiceImpl` class directly and initialize with the constructor. This makes sure that the once the `main` function initializes `SharedPreferences` once, there is no subsequent need of calling `getInstance` again inside the `getValue` function.
2. The `get` functions of `SharedPreferences` return the T? value directly and not Future<T?> value, hence there is no need for the `getValue` function to return `Future<T?>`, so I changed it's definition.
3. Changed the function signature in `key_value_class.dart`
4. Changed the main function to pass a `SharedPreferences` object to the constructor of `KeyValueStorageServiceImpl`.
5. Gave an alternative approach by making the `KeyValueStorageServiceImpl` into a Singleton.

You can read my comments in the code if you like.

`key_value_storage.dart`

```dart
import 'key_value_storage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class KeyValueStorageServiceImpl extends KeyValueStorageService {
  /// The instance of shared preferences is declared once for every object you create of this type.
  final SharedPreferences prefs;

  /// Call the `SharedPreferences.getInstance();` function outside of this class in order to not need to return a 
  /// future from the `getValue` method.
  KeyValueStorageServiceImpl(this.prefs);  

  /// The `get` operation returns the value itself, not a future.
  @override
  T? getValue<T>(String key) {
    switch (T) {
      case String:
        return prefs.getString(key) as T?;
      case int:
        return prefs.getInt(key) as T?;
      case double:
        return prefs.getDouble(key) as T?;
      case bool:
        return prefs.getBool(key) as T?;
      case List:
        return prefs.getStringList(key) as T?;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'No implementation Get for ${T.runtimeType}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> removeKey(String key) async {
    return await prefs.remove(key);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setKeyValue<T>(String key, T value) async {
    switch (T) {
      case String:
        await prefs.setString(key, value as String);
        break;
      case int:
        await prefs.setInt(key, value as int);
        break;
      case double:
        await prefs.setDouble(key, value as double);
        break;
      case bool:
        await prefs.setBool(key, value as bool);
        break;
      case List:
        await prefs.setStringList(key, value as List<String>);
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'No implementation Set for  ${T.runtimeType}');
    }
  }
}
```

`key_value_class.dart`

```dart
abstract class KeyValueStorageService {
  Future<void> setKeyValue<T>(String key, T value);
  T? getValue<T>(String key);
  Future<bool> removeKey(String key);
}
```

`main()` function

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Enviroment.initEnvirontment();
  //! Key Value instance for main async 
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // use this wherever you need to call `getValue`
  var keyValueStorageService = KeyValueStorageServiceImpl(prefs);
  await initializeDateFormatting('es_ES', null);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp())));
}
```

### Alternative Approach using Singleton

`key_value_storage.dart`

```dart
import 'key_value_storage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class KeyValueStorageServiceImpl extends KeyValueStorageService {
  /// The instance of shared preferences
  final SharedPreferences prefs;

  /// The single instance which will remain all through the app lifecycle
  static KeyValueStorageServiceImpl? _instance;

  /// Getter for the instance
  static KeyValueStorageServiceImpl get instance => _instance!;

  /// Set the instance value, if not already set, by creating an object
  /// of `KeyValueStorageServiceImpl` type and passing the SharedPreferences.
  static void setSharedPreferences(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    _instance ??= KeyValueStorageServiceImpl._(prefs);
  }

  /// Private Constructor to prevent multiple instances of this class.
  KeyValueStorageServiceImpl._(this.prefs);  

  /// The `get` operation returns the value itself, not a future.
  @override
  T? getValue<T>(String key) {
    switch (T) {
      case String:
        return prefs.getString(key) as T?;
      case int:
        return prefs.getInt(key) as T?;
      case double:
        return prefs.getDouble(key) as T?;
      case bool:
        return prefs.getBool(key) as T?;
      case List:
        return prefs.getStringList(key) as T?;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'No implementation Get for ${T.runtimeType}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> removeKey(String key) async {
    return await prefs.remove(key);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setKeyValue<T>(String key, T value) async {
    switch (T) {
      case String:
        await prefs.setString(key, value as String);
        break;
      case int:
        await prefs.setInt(key, value as int);
        break;
      case double:
        await prefs.setDouble(key, value as double);
        break;
      case bool:
        await prefs.setBool(key, value as bool);
        break;
      case List:
        await prefs.setStringList(key, value as List<String>);
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError(
            'No implementation Set for  ${T.runtimeType}');
    }
  }
}
```

`main()` function

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Enviroment.initEnvirontment();

  //! Key Value instance for main async 
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  KeyValueStorageServiceImpl.setSharedPreferences(prefs);
  
  await initializeDateFormatting('es_ES', null);
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((value) => runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp())));
}
```

Now wherever you need to get a value, you can just do the following

`var value = KeyValueStorageServiceImpl.instance.getValue<Type>('key');`

Hope this solves your issue! Happy Coding! :)

### How the Singleton approach works:

Basically, a Singleton class means that only one instance of that Class can be created, and hence it gets the name, Singleton. A Singleton class has only one static instance of itself, and as such, the static instance is available throughout the lifecycle of the app, from the app initializing to the app being closed. Thus, A Singleton enables us to declare global data and functions, which can be accessed from any class, as we don't need the `BuildContext` like in the case of `InheritedWidget`s.

Comment: Great, I appreciate it. Singleton Approach worked, but I don't fully understand how a Singleton works, can you explain or expand?

Comment: Happy to help! :) Sure, I'll update my answer.